# In R, how to check if a letter or punctuation mark is located in a specified location in a string?

Tags: r, string

Let's say I have two strings:

```
text1 <- "Mr. JONES. The weather today is nice."
text2 <- "Mr. JONES, how are you doing today?"
```

Both start with "Mr. JONES" but one has a period after Mr. JONES while the other has a comma. How do I check if the character located one position to the left of the second white space (or, alternatively, one position to the right of JONES) is a period?

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps

```
grep('[^ ]+ +[^ .]+[.]', x)
#[1] 1 3
```

Or

```
grep('(?<=[A-Z]),(?= )', x, perl=TRUE)
#[1] 2
```

Or

```
grep('JONES\\.', x)
#[1] 1 3
```

#### data

```
text1 <- "Mr. JONES. The weather today is nice."
text2 <- "Mr. JONES, how are you doing today?"
text3 <- "Mr.   JONES. The weather today is nice."
x <- c(text1, text2, text3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below.

> How do I check if the character located one position to the left of the second white space

```
> x <- c("Mr. JONES. The weather today is nice.", "Mr. JONES, how are you doing today?")
> grep('^[^ ]* [^ ]*\\. ', x)
[1] 1
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bL8zT9/1)

> one position to the right of JONES) is a period?

```
> grep('(?<=JONES)\\. ', x, perl=T)
[1] 1
> grep('JONES\\K\\. ', x, perl=T)
[1] 1
```

Comment: yes, because the character before the second space is not a dot. That's what op asked. He wants to match the lines which has a `.` before the second space.